# iOS Game Center. How to find out whether app is inviting a friend or looking for a random game?

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm working with class `GKMatchmakerViewController`. Its interface allows user either start a random game or invite user's friend. I want the app to process each of these two actions in a specific way. The issue is that i cannot find any clue to distinguish between these two actions. The inner implementation is concealed by GameKit and there are no (or at least i cannot find) delegate methods, like `didStartLookingForRandomMatch` and `didSendInvitationToFriend`. All i've got is `didFindMatch`delegate method but it doesn't specify what type of the match has been found. Seems like i've explained my issue clearly. Any ideas? Thanks, everyone